# Highlight a single button instance in a complex React page

Tags: reactjs, redux

My page is composed of hierarchy of classes and many reusable components. Multiple instances of a button component can exist anywhere in the page and on click they fire actions that populate different types of data in a common sidebar list component.

The requirement is to highlight the button that was last clicked to load the data in that sidebar list. Of course, it also means to remove highlighting from the previous button. Since these button can exist in different components, I cannot manage state in one parent component.

I am not able to find a solution in pure React. I don't want to use jQuery rather just stick to React. Note I do use Redux in the app though and would be fine with leveraging Redux state if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should most definitely use Redux. You'll need to create a variable in Redux that gets updated whenever an action takes place that would require you to highlight the button on the page. Then use conditional styling for the button based on that variable.